# Orbeon 4.8 Postgres Problems

Tags: postgresql, orbeon

I cant seem to get orbeon working with postgres.

In WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml I have

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>OrbeonDS</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgresql</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

Then in WEB-INF/web.xml I have

```
...
<resource-ref>
    <description>DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>OrbeonDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
...
```

My standalone.xml file for jboss contains

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/postgresql" pool-name="postgresql" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Orbeon</connection-url>
    <driver>postgres</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>myuser</user-name>
        <password>mypassword</password>
    </security>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

On startup the connection is bound and I have a working connection to the database. Orbeon also starts up ok and I am presented with the main screen. When I click on form runner to view my forms I get the database error popup.

In my log file, the error that appears is

```
error caught {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/service/postgresql/form"}

An error has occured
env/jdbc/mysql -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.postgresql
```

My properties-local.xml also contains the lines

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="postgresql"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.datasource" value="postgresql"/>
```

Any ideas on what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've already used a relational database persistence layer as well, but in tomcat not in Jboss.

Have you installed the JDBC driver as a module?
Follow the instruction from the following link, but using postgresql driver instead of mysql driver. http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-Setup-a-JDBC-datasource .

Also, the property oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.datasource matches the resource name (jdbc/*) that you setup in server.xml. So, if the resource name is for example 'jdbc/postgresql', then oxf.fr.persistence.postgresql.datasource has to be 'postgresql'.

Comment: Hi,@Inanda Menezes, I'm unable to configure the Postgres DB for the Orbeon Forms. Please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201679/orbeon-forms-postgres-db-connection